# Change dynamic field title in solr select query

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I am using solr to retrieve results from a cassandra table.

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  field1 uuid,
  field2 text ,
  bfield blob,
  custmdata_<text, text>,
  PRIMARY KEY (field1)
);
```

**Table content**

```
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES ( 62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204,"test1", { 'custmdata_data1'  : 'data1value', 'custmdata_data2' : 'data2value' });
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES ( e26690db-dd54-4b61-b002-d3c07125f359,"test2", { 'custmdata_data5'  : 'data5value', 'custmdata_data1' : 'mydata1value' });
```

I am able to retrieve the results using solr query.

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "field1": "62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204",
        "field2": "test1",
         "custmdata_data1":"data1value",
         "custmdata_data2" : "data2value"
      },
      {
        "field1": "e26690db-dd54-4b61-b002-d3c07125f359",
        "field2": "test2",
         "custmdata_data5":"data5value",
         "custmdata_data1" : "mydata1value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to specify the field name in result so that I can retrieve the dynamic fields without having the field name prefix? I need result like this:

```
{
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1
      },
      "response": {
        "numFound": 2,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
          {
            "field1": "62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204",
            "field2": "test1",
             "data1":"data1value",
             "data2" : "data2value"
          },
          {
            "field1": "e26690db-dd54-4b61-b002-d3c07125f359",
            "field2": "test2",
             "data5":"data5value",
             "data1" : "mydata1value"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

**Update:**
From datastax documentaion, I found that,

> Avoid or limit the use of dynamic fields. Lucene allocates memory for
>   each unique field (column) name, so if you have a row with columns A,
>   B, C, and another row with B, D, E, Lucene allocates 5 chunks of
>   memory. For millions of rows, the heap is unwieldy.

So is there a better way to achieve dynamic field based filtering in Solr? What I need is to filter against custom fields that may vary for each insert.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling your dyn field `custmdata_` call it `data` and that should get rid of the bit you don't want.

Otherwise removing the dyn field prepended label is not supported but you can rename returned fields with `fl`: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Field_alias

If you're worried about having too many dyn fields, try to workaround it with some C* collection type if you scenario lends itself to that.

Comment: I used data1, data2 etc as just examples. It can be anything like "filename", "temperature" as the use prefers. So can't follow your first advice.